# How to perform multipe task under single android background service?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, background-service

So what my app is doing compressing videos and reducing its size. 
For this, I am using an Android background service and it's currently working fine. 
Also looks good for one selected video, now what I am thinking what if the user selects multiple videos how can I compress all these videos using a background service in a better way..
compressing video takes time and for each video, it depends on video length and some other properties.
For now what I have done so far is just a rough idea...

I am starting a service providing all video details passing it as intent extras..like below

```
        val intent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, selectedVideos)          // selectedVideo => ArrayList<Video> 
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, compressionPrams)        // compressionPrams => Hasmap<String, String>
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, intent)
```

Now my service is like this...

```
class MyService : Service() {

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    ...retrieving all data from intent extras...
    val **selectedVideos** ArrayList<Video>...    // supposed we've 6 video needs to compress 
    val **compressionPrams** HashMap<*, *>...

    // Now after this, I am parsing all compression prams and building command to execute for
    // compressing video. (Below is just a rough idea of my app functionality.)

    // Note: CompressingVideo.compressAsync runs in its own separate background thread.
    CompressingVideo.compressAsync(selectedVideos[0], object: CompletionCallback { status ->
              // Whenever the compression is completed we get notified by callback...
              // Now the first video compression is completed, processing another one...
           
              // Here I am checking if I have more videos to process then update command and prams 
              // and then start its compression
              CompressingVideo.compress(seletedVideo[...], this)   // passing this as completion callback
          }
      )
   }
}
```

So now what do you think..is this approach good or is there any other more better way to do it...
The supposed first video takes 3 mint, 2nd 10 mint, 3rd 5 mint...and so on till 6. approx 30 mint. to complete all tasks.
One thing came to my mind what if I pass a second video to the service by myself when the previous one gets compressed, like telling the service hey this needs to process as well.
after starting the service can we send more data so that `onStartCommand(...)` gets called again to process another video...etc